Is it possible to change the default Agent update URL in Azure DevOps Server?
While updating Agents in Azure DevOps Server, I've encountered an issue where each Agent cannot access the default URL vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net.

Since we're operating within an intranet environment and prefer not to allow access to this site, we also want to avoid reinstalling each Agent individually.
Is there a way to change this default URL so that the Agents can update without accessing vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net?

I found a solution where the compressed file can be placed into a specified directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops-2022#can-i-update-my-agents-that-are-part-of-an-azure-devops-server-pool
Transfer the downloaded package files to each Azure DevOps Server Application Tier by using a method of your choice (such as USB drive, Network transfer, and so on). Place the agent files under the following folder:
Windows: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Azure DevOps\Agents

It's great that you've found the answer and share the useful info here. You can consider accepting it as answer so that more members can benefit from the accepted answer.

No, this isn't possible. If you won't let the agents access this location, you'll manually have to update the agents.
